# Redux actions are not called on subsequent re-mounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am working on a web app, and one of the components/routes has a caching problem. There is a "master" page from which users could view the detail page. When the detail page is first constructed, it loads the data correctly, but when users go back to the master and choose another item to view the details they are presented with stale data. The loading is done from `componentDidMount()` and it is being called on the first mount and remount, just fine.

First, the following actions are executed: `LOAD_CHALLENGE_DETAILS` and `LOAD_CHALLENGE_DETAILS_SUCCESS`. On the subsequent views, there is no `success`.

I load the data in saga, as below:

```
import { takeLatest, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import api from 'utils/api';
import { loadChallengeDetailsSuccess } from './actions';
import { LOAD_CHALLENGE_DETAILS } from './constants';

function* loadChallengeDetailsData({ id }) {
  console.log('loadChallengeDetailsData');
  const response = yield call(api, `/challenges/details/${id}`);
  const respJson = yield call([response, 'json']);
  yield put(loadChallengeDetailsSuccess(respJson));
}

/**
 * Root saga manages watcher lifecycle
 */
export default function* getData() {
  yield takeLatest(LOAD_CHALLENGE_DETAILS, loadChallengeDetailsData);
}
```

It prints to the console:

```
action: {type: "powerwalks/Challenges/LOAD_CHALLENGE_DETAILS", id: "0d6e0252-a5ce-4e46-a3cb-042e2b110214"}
saga.js:9 loadChallengeDetailsData
reducer.js:12 action: {type: "powerwalks/Challenges/LOAD_CHALLENGE_DETAILS_SUCCESS", payload: {…}, @@redux-saga/SAGA_ACTION: true}
```

then after I go back and choose another "record," it only prints:

```
action: {type: "powerwalks/Challenges/LOAD_CHALLENGE_DETAILS", id: "72459cb0-e0d3-49bb-81f0-7b753f2de5a2"}
```

I am perplexed as to what is happening. Please advise.

Comment: Why do you change context here? `yield call([response, 'json']);`

Comment: I believe that the root saga - `getData` is executed on remount and somehow it does not call the `loadChallengeDetailsData` function. I don't understand why, yet...

Comment: `call` is a blocking action, it won't go further if it doesn't resolve. `yield call([response, 'json']);` leads to nowhere atm

Comment: @kinduser see https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1141

Comment: Could you tell me what actually does `call([response, 'json']);` this do?

Comment: Ok - made some research. What library do u use for fetching?